# How to get all descendants of an element using webdriver?

Tags: java, collections, selenium, webdriver

There is this element which has child elements, those child elements again have child elements and so on. I would like to get all elements that are descendants of the element. Thanks.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try this one:

(Java)

```
List<WebElement> childs = rootWebElement.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
```

(C#)

```
IReadOnlyList<IWebElement> childs = rootWebElement.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*"));
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same using CSS?

Comment: `By.cssSelector("*")` - this should work the same way as `By.xpath(".//*")` but not 100% sure that it will not search across all the document (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html). Why XPath solution doesn't work for you?

Comment: The application I'm working is compatible only with IE. Using CSS is preferable over XPath as XPath execution is slow compared to CSS in IE.

Comment: I see... Try XPath - it's much more quicker now in IE with WebDriver comparing to Selenium RC. But still there are some issues with performance on very complex XPath-expressions.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: This will gives you all the available elements in that page.

Comment: `rootWebElement` is an instance of `WebElement` class. Class `WebElement` implements `SearchContext` interface as well as class `WebDriver`. So the search is done within some particular element - not within the whole page.

Comment: And if you want only the top-level children of a particular element, just drop one of the slashes: `List<WebElement> topLevelChildren = rootWebElement.findElements(By.xpath("./*"));`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this one

```
List<WebElement> allDescendantsChilds = rootWebElement.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@class='parent']//*"));
```

The above thing will gives you all descendant child elements (not only immediate child) of **parent tr**

Comment: what exactly tr is doing there? The element need not to be a table.

Comment: For example I've mentioned like tr. In tr place you replace with with parent tag which has child > child like that 

(ex : tr > td > div > input ) in this case it will give td,div,input elements

Comment: Lets say There is a table which has 10 trs, and each row has 10 tds and each td has 10 spans. If the element is table, what I expect to get is 10trs, 100tds and 1000spans but your code just gives 1tr 10tds 100 spans?

Comment: NO ..It will give (It is giving also I've verified) all trs (10), tds (100) , spans (1000) . <tr1><td1><10Spans></td1><td2><10Spans>...</td1>....</tr1>...<tr10><td1><10Spans></td1><td2><10Spans>...</td1>....</tr10> in this format it will give..just check it.

Comment: Ok, which elmeent does the rootWebElement holds? it holds parent element? and do I've to replace tr with the first child of the parent element? Sorry I am new to XPath, can you explain your code little more?

Comment: Yes. It holds the parent element. In case of above example table is the parent so you need to specify like List<WebElement> ele=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='tableID']//*"));

Answer (score -3):

Try this one:

```
List<WebElement> childs = rootWebElement.findElements(By.tagName(".//*"));
```

Comment: It's a copy of the first answer.