# java- webdriver click on a list element

Tags: java, html, list, selenium

```
<div class="class0">
  <div class="class1">
    <input tabindex="4" id="pqr" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  </div>

  <ul class="class2">
    <li class="group-result">polka</li>
    <li class="active-result group-option" style="" data-array-      index="1">abcd</li>
    <li class="active-result group-option" style="" data-array-index="2">efgh</li>
    <li class="group-result">ijkl</li>
    <li class="active-result group" style="" data-array-index="3">abcd</li>
    <li class="active-result group" style="" data-array-index="4"></li>
    <li class="active-result" style="" data-array-index="5">xyz</li>
  </ul>
```

Pardon me if I can't reproduce the whole code here. In the above piece of html, the user is prompted to type in the input box and autosuggestions are generated. What you see above is what one gets after typing in the box.

I need to click on an li element, say xyz. One approach is to get the ul element and then get all its children. Then iterate through them and select the correct one by checking their inner texts. So, I tried

```
WebElement a1 = driver.findElement(By.className("class0"));
WebElement a2 = a1.findElement(By.className("class2"));

List <WebElement> a3 = a2.findElements(By.xpath(".//*));
System.out.println(a3.size());
```

as suggested in this question's reply : [How to get all descendants of an element using webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052368/how-to-get-all-descendants-of-an-element-using-webdriver)

But the print statement prints 0, i.e no child is found

Can someone please suggest why ?

Also any other approach suggestion would be highly welcome.

Thanks

Comment: does your java contain code to type in characters in text box?

Comment: Yes Amith.....I mentioned only a piece of my code above. But my code types into the input box and I can see it....also, the list elements wouldn't come otherwise

Comment: `List <WebElement> a3 = a2.findElements(By.xpath(".//*));`..double quote is missing in this statement, guess its a typo...have you tried using other xpaths or cssSelectors?

Comment: Its a typo, yes....my bad.  I tried cssSelector with data-array-index, didn't work. Also, compound classnames aren't accepted too

Comment: can you try this `findElements(By.cssSelector(".class2 > li[class*='result']"))`

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until the `class0` div is present in the DOM before querying for its children:

```
WebDriverWait wdw = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20);
WebElement a1 = wdw.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("class0")));

WebElement a2 = a1.findElement(By.className("class2"));

List <WebElement> a3 = a2.findElements(By.xpath(".//*));
System.out.println(a3.size());
```

Comment: I do use waitVar.....that doesn't help. The code gets the a2 element easily, its the child elements that it misses. I get a zero as the output of the last print statement